# Java MD5 Hash Not Matching .NET Hash

Tags: java, hash, md5

I have a webservice that is written in C# handling some validation of values.  In it I need to check a MD5 hash generated in the calling Java client.

The Java client generates the hash in this manner

```
Charset utf8Charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

byte[] bytesOfPhrase = phrase.getBytes(utf8Charset);
MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

byte[] thedigest = md.digest(bytesOfPhrase);
this._AuthenticationToken = new String(thedigest, utf8Charset);
```

The C# webservice generates its has in this manner:

```
private static string HashString(string toHash)
{
    MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5Provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

    byte[] hashedBytes = md5Provider.ComputeHash(_StringEncoding.GetBytes(toHash));
    return Convert.ToBase64String(hashedBytes);
}
```

I've tried several charsets in the Java code, but none of them produce a string that is anywhere similar to the Java produced string.  Using hard coded values that are the same during every call (meaning that I've hardcoded the parameters so the hashes should match) still produces an odd Java string.

C# Example of hashed values:

> 6wM7McddLBjofdFJ3rU6/g==

I'd post the example of the string Java produces, but it has some very odd characters that I do not think I can paste in here.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fundamentally *broken* code:

```
// Badly broken
byte[] thedigest = md.digest(bytesOfPhrase);
this._AuthenticationToken = new String(thedigest, utf8Charset);
```

Never, ever, ever try to encode arbitrary binary data by passing it to the String constructor. *Always* use base64, or hex, or something like that. [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/codec/) has a Base64 encoder, or this [public domain version](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) has a slightly more pleasant API.

The equivalent C# would be:

```
// Equally broken
byte[] hashedBytes = md5Provider.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toHash));
return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hashedBytes);
```

What are the chances that the binary data produced by an MD5 digest is *actually* a valid UTF-8 byte sequence?

Two other things to note:

- You can get hold of an MD5 hash slightly more simply in .NET using the `MD5` class:

  ```
  byte[] hash;
  using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
  {
      hash = md5.ComputeHash(bytes);
  }
  // Use hash
  ```

  Note the use of the `using` statement to dispose of the instance afterwards. My main preference for this is that it's easier to remember, read and type `MD5` than `MD5CryptoServiceProvider` :)
- You haven't made it clear what `_StringEncoding` is, but the code should really just use `Encoding.UTF8` to match the Java.

Comment: You should also call `Dispose` on MD5 as well (or a `using`). This has some security implications, and if you are usinge `*CryptoServiceProvider` implementations, releases some unmanaged resoruces.

Comment: _StringEncoding is in fact UTF8. Sorry, I didn't include it in the top of my example. I need to do better at proof reading.  Quick question as I am a bit confused. In your C# code it appears to no longer be a base64 string, hence it would match the java code above, correct?  In that case I would not need to have a base64 string in the Java client, again correct?

Comment: @Mike G: The only C# code I've given is explicitly *broken* code, and a replacement for the bit performing the hashing itself. If you need to communicate using text, base64 is the way to go in both clients.

Comment: @Jon Well, I thought this was a good solution, but I cannot reference that Apache Commons Codec somehow when this runs inside Cognos. Is there any downfall to not converting the values to base64?

Comment: @Mike: Well you haven't told us what you're *doing* with these hash values. Do you need them as strings? If so, you've got to find *some* safe conversion, and base64 or hex are the obvious options. Have you tried the public domain code I linked to as well?

Answer (score 3):

Your C# digest is in Base64, but your Java digest is not. Convert `thedigest` to Base64 as well.

Comment: Could you explain a little more in depth?  I'm trying to do the following: this._AuthenticationToken = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(thedigest); but I'm getting an error: Access restriction: The method encode(byte[]) from the type CharacterEncoder is not accessible due to restriction on required library C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\rt.jar Am I still missing something?

Comment: @Mike G: Yes, you're not meant to use sun.* classes. See the links in my answer for two other options for base64 encoding in Java.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you encode the bytes using Base64. In Java, you interpret the bytes as a UTF-8-string.

Answer (score 0):

Your C# code outputs MD5 hash as BASE64-encoded, but java code does not.
A generic method to compare two MD5 hashes is to compare its hexadecimal presentation (16bytes -> 32digits).